# How to use objects.filter() to select the Boolean True posts only

Tags: python, django

I want to establish a queryset of `Post` model which filters only the `published=True` in the `Public` view.

I have tried the following:

```
return Post.objects.filter('published'==True).all()
```

**views.py**

```
class PublicList(ListView):
    template_name = 'publish.html'
    context_object_name = 'items'
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter('published'==True).all()
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def publish(self):
       self.published=True
        self.save()

    def unpublish(self):
        self.published=False
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The traceback errors:

```
 File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\Desktop\Django\prac_18\firstapp\views.py" in    get_queryset
82.         return Post.objects.filter('published'==True).all()

 File "C:\Users\AngryBuLLz\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.filter(published=True)
```

Instead of

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.filter('published'==True).all()
```

Reference can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters).

Comment: how  can i get the lists of those builtin filter(__args)? e.g. filter(__lte)